# Finding spot on an image - mathematical way?

Tags: php, math, image-processing, gd

I need to find a predefined area on an image and replace it with the other image (by just embedding the latter). The predefined spot would be a variable size rectangle area filled with solid background of the previously agreed colour.

Any advise on how do I achieve this?

I guess I can find a first pixel of the specified colour by doing a loop and going through the image row by row, pixel by pixel, but I feel like that's not the most efficient solution. Since the spot is supposed to be rather big, I also thought about going across the picture (please see the attachment below).

[image: finding spot]

So I need help in defining those loops. I believe I'll have to use some mathematical functions for that.

For example, if the big picture was square, the diagonal loop (the yellow *EF* line) would use the simplified linear function `y=x` (`y=1x+0`), but it's not likely to really be square. So I'll have to use the extended full linear function `y=kx+b` where `k` will have something to do with the rectangle size (I thought `k=height/width`), and `b` will be just 0. So the loop will look like:

```
$k = 1080/1920;
for ( $x=1920; $x>0; $x-- ) {
    $y = $k*$x;
}
```

But thats the yellow one, and the most simple I guess. Now, how do I define the others? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why do you guys vote for closing this?

Answer (score 3):

Get pieces of your sub-image you're searching and search it in the big image.

You can use ImageMagick's sub-image search:

```
compare -verbose -dissimilarity-threshold 0.1 -subimage-search subimage.jpg bigimage.jpg
```

Read more about this [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) , [here](http://www.multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=22057) and [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18334).

It will either tell you "TooDissimilar" or it will tell you the x,y position of the subimage.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. The *It will either tell you ...* update you added clarified it a lot. Not sure if ImageMagick is available on the shared host that's used, but I will consider it as an option.

Comment: Update: I'm not searching for the sub-image, the sub-image is what I will embed after I find the spot. So it's not really about comparing I guess because there's nothing to compare with.

Comment: "The predefined spot would be a variable size rectangle area filled with solid background of the previously agreed colour" -- this is how you defined the spot you're searching for, so why not generate that rectangle, write it as an image to disk, and then use compare with subimage-search to find it in the big picture. That is one way of doing it