# Need to click darkest spot in image

Tags: javascript, php, image

For one of my current projects I need to be able to find the coordinates of the darkest spot in an image. The image will look something like this:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Obviously the dark spot will be in a different place every time, so I need to somehow detect the X and Y values of the center of this spot. I'd prefer to do this with JavaScript or PHP.

I know almost nothing about image recognition, but I do not expect any of you to write a complete script for me. Just a nudge in the right direction alone would be awesome because I have been looking but can't even find out where to start or what kind of functions I would be able to use for this. I assume the best way to go about this is to convert the image to b/w and then increase the contrast so the black spot becomes really clear?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523104/finding-spot-on-an-image-mathematical-way

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you the darkest pixel (depending on how you define dark).  This example uses a data uri as it does not work with cross domain images.  If you want the darkest region (as suggested by your image) you could sample a region with getImageData() and average the brightness of the pixels in the region.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var minBrightness = 256;
var minLocation = [-1, -1];

for (var x=0; x < img.width; x++){
  for (var y=0; y < img.height; y++){

    var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    var brightness = 0.34 * data[0] + 0.5 * data[1] + 0.16 * data[2]; 
    if (brightness >= minBrightness) { continue; }
    minBrightness = brightness;
    minLocation = [x, y];

  }
}

console.log("Darkest Point [" + minLocation + "] brightness(" + minBrightness + ")");
```

```html
<img id="myImage" width="70" height="55" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. So sorry for the delay in my response! I've recently gotten back into trying this, and currently have this code with the help of some others on Stackoverflow:  http://jsfiddle.net/brampower/tw08fdhf Unfortunately this method gets the darkest pixel and as you mentioned I should be looking for the darkest region. I have messed around with geImageData() but was not able to find a reliable method. Since you mentioned it in your earlier comment, would you be able to give a(nother) hand?