# Javascript - find darkest region of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, ocr, pixel

I am trying to use Javascript to find the darkest region of an image.
So far, this is what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/brampower/bv78rmz8/

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
} else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
        case r:
            h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
            break;
        case g:
            h = (b - r) / d + 2;
            break;
        case b:
            h = (r - g) / d + 4;
            break;
    }
    h /= 6;
}

return ({
    h: h,
    s: s,
    l: l,
})
}

function solve_darkest(url, callback) {
var image = new Image();
image.src = url;

image.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width  = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300);

    var pixel = 0;
    var darkest_pixel_lightness = 100;
    var darkest_pixel_location = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
        red = imgData.data[i + 0];
        green = imgData.data[i + 1];
        blue = imgData.data[i + 2];
        alpha = imgData.data[i + 3];

        var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
        var lightness = hsl.l;

        if (lightness < darkest_pixel_lightness) {
            darkest_pixel_lightness = lightness;
            darkest_pixel_location = pixel;
        }

        pixel++;
    }

    var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/200);
    var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*200);

    callback(x,y);
};
}

image_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/j6oJO8s.png'; 
solve_darkest(image_url, function(x, y) {
alert('x: '+x+' y: '+y);
});
```

It won't work in JSFiddle because of the tainted canvas, but hopefully that will give you an idea. For the sample image, my JS is currently returning the following coordinates:
x: 140  y: 117

These are not the correct coordinates. The darkest pixel of this image should be around the following coordinates:
x: 95  y: 204

I just can't figure out why the coordinates are so off. Anyone here that would be willing to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to click darkest spot in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739177/need-to-click-darkest-spot-in-image)

Comment: Thank you, but the code in that question did not seem to help unfortunately. I've started from scratch, hence the new question. I feel like I am very close, but can't seem to figure out why the coordinates returned to me are not the ones I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just tested your jsfiddle.

For the tainted canvas just change crossOrigin property:

```
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

For the incorrect pixel, there are several problems.

1. Incorrect canvas size. If the image is smaller than the canvas size, the algorithm tests pixels which are not in the image, but are in the canvas. Since you don't drop the pixels which are transparent, you also test the 0, 0, 0 (RGB) pixel which is supposed to be black #000000.
2. Incorrect 1-dimensional array to 2-dimensional transformation. The formula you are using is incorrect, because you set the width and height to 300, but use 200 in the formula. I suggest creating a variable and using that as a reference.

If you doubt that the pixel is exactly there, create a small picture, like 5x5 px size and check if the algorithm returns what you expect.

I updated the jsfiddle, I think this is correct now. Also, removed the img element in HTML and just appended the canvas to the body: https://jsfiddle.net/Draznel/597u5h0c/1/

Comment: This is great. I have an updated JSF where you could see that I am not quite getting the result that I am looking for yet; the end goal is to find the coordinates of the dark box in the image, or the darkest region if you will: https://jsfiddle.net/brampower/tw08fdhf/ 

The current result is x = 290, y = 138. That specific pixel does not fall in the dark square region. Perhaps it would be easier to sample a region with getImageData() and average the brightness of pixels in the region, although admittedly I do not have experience with doing so. Do you think this would be a better solution?

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the rgbToHsl function. Try it out with different functions. I think, the problem is, that the darkest pixel is in the 290:138. You see, even if you paint over a darker rectangle, if a single pixel anywhere in the image has lower lightness, it will be darker. For example, you have a rectangle, where the lightness is 0.1 or so, but if somewhere in the image exists a full black pixel (#000000) it will be the darkest pixel in the image.

Comment: I think that is the case here. I added this line `console.log(red, green, blue);` when a new darker pixel is found. The darkest pixel found is #060206, and this is darker than any pixel before it. So I think the function works correctly. Try it out with different images, find in the internet a small light image, like blue sky image, edit it and add in a dark pixel and see if this algorithm finds it.

Comment: Also, call this function after calculating x and y, to see where the darkest pixel is, in the canvas.

`var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth="6";
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.rect(x-5,y-5,10,10);
ctx.fill();`

Please upvote this answer, if it was the most useful here.

Comment: I had previously upvoted your answer but unfortunately it's not being reflected on the site because I don't have 15 reputation yet. Please know that your help is much appreciated. You're right that the function is currently working correctly; I ran some tests on a white image with a single black pixel and it was able to find the dark pixel consistently. For what I am trying to accomplish I need to find the darkest region though. My guess is that I need to take a sample of 10x10 pixels and get the average lightness of those while looping through the image. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: I have 0 experience with what you are trying to accomplish. However, I have experience in game development, so it's not that hard to apply what I know to this. So, you are trying to find the darkest block, and not the darkest symbol. There are many ways to do that. First of all, you should convert the image to 2d float array which consists of pixel lightness values. Then you can do many things with that.

Comment: First thing you can do, would be to search not the lowest score in pixels, but in blocks. So, you could split the array into 10x10 blocks(100 pixel) and calculate the sum of lightness. Then compare it with other blocks. You'll find the darkest block. It would be close to what you are trying to achieve, but it would find a hardcoded grid block(basically, it will always have x position which divides by 10 and y position which divides by 10. Difficult to explain, let's hope you understand that.

Comment: Another way, which would take a lot of time to compute, would be to have a function, which calculates the lightness of pixels around it(like a 5-8 pixels range/or a rectangle with the pixel as the center) and then put the result in another array. Then you would find the pixel, is in the darkest area of the image. Though, keep in mind that it will take a long time to compute for larger images. You could try to skip pixels(for the first step, not the area darkness calculating) which have lightness value > 0.5 or so. Idk, try it out and let me know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without the JSFiddle working, my best guess would be that the logic in

```
var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/200);
var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*200);
```

is incorrect for two reasons.

1) The image is 300 pixels in width/height, not 200

2) The imagedata is ordered by x first and y second

To get the correct x and y coordinates, I think the following code would work:

```
var x = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location / imageWidth);
var y = darkest_pixel_location % imageWidth;
```

Comment: You're correct; hardcoding them to 200x200 was a mistake that was left after I did some testing with another image. With the help of Emestas above I came to this updated JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brampower/tw08fdhf

Unfortunately this is still not the result I was hoping for. I'm trying to get the x and y coords of the darker box of the image; I figured that the darkest pixel would be inside of that box but it does not appear to be that way. I might need to look into testing a region and average the brightness of pixels in the region, although admittedly I do not have experience doing so

Answer (score 0):

A good time to realise the nasty consequences of hard-coded variables...

You're creating a canvas of 300x300 and drawing a png of the same dimensions to it. Unfortunately, you then use 200 to determine the x,y pos given the index of the selected pixel. Hint: make a 300x300 image that's white. Set *a single pixel* at (95,204) to black. Run your unmodified code and you'll get 95,306. Change to same as image size and you'll get (95,204) as your answer.

So, you can hardly complain that the index into a 300x300 image returns the wrong position when manipulated in a way that would be appropriate for the index into a 200x200 image.

Personally, I'd replace:

```
var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/200);
var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*200);
```

with

```
var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/this.width);
var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*this.width);
```

That will then convert an index back into *correct* x,y coordinates.

That said, the image you've provided actually doesn't have it's darkest spot at the indicated location. The pixel at 95,204 has the value of #37614e, or rgb(55,97,78).

Thus, I hope you can now see the purpose of my suggestion of a single dark pixel in an otherwise light image. You can reduce the number of issues you're trying to debug to one at a time. In this case - "can I convert an index back into 2d coordinates?". Once done, "do I have a dark spot actually where I think it is?"

In your case - the answer to both of these questions was **no**! Not exactly the most advantageous place from which to start debugging...

---

some comments were made and a better understanding of the problem at hand gained.

---

Okay, as per the discussion in the comments - the task is to find the upper-left corner of a darkened region in an image - such a search should average results over an (as yet) unknown area such that local minimums or maximums (dark or light pixels) will not adversely affect the identified area of interest.

Ideally, one may run the code iteratively - try with a block-size of 1, then a block-size of 2, etc, etc, increasing the block-size until the results from two runs are the same or within a certain limit.

I.e if I search with a block-size of 9 and get the location 93,211 and then get the same with a block-size of 10 (whereas all previous block-size values returned a different result) then I'd probably feel fairly confident I'd correctly identified the area of interest.

Here's some code to chew on. You'll notice I've left your function and created another, very similar one. I hope you'll find it suitable. :)

```js
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByClass(clss,parent){return (parent==undefined?document:parent).getElementsByClassName(clss)}
function allByTag(tag,parent){return (parent==undefined?document:parent).getElementsByTagName(tag)}
function toggleClass(elem,clss){elem.classList.toggle(clss)}
function addClass(elem,clss){elem.classList.add(clss)}
function removeClass(elem,clss){elem.classList.remove(clss)}
function hasClass(elem,clss){elem.classList.contains(clss)}

// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

// callback gets data via the .target.result field of the param passed to it.
function loadFileObject(fileObj, loadedCallback){var a = new FileReader();a.onload = loadedCallback;a.readAsDataURL( fileObj );}

function ajaxGet(url, onLoad, onError)
{
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.onload = function(){onLoad(this);}
 ajax.onerror = function(){console.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
 ajax.open("GET",url,true);
 ajax.send();
}

function ajaxPost(url, phpPostVarName, data, onSucess, onError)
{
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.onload = function(){ onSucess(this);}
 ajax.onerror = function() {console.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
 ajax.open("POST", url, true);
 ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajax.send(phpPostVarName+"=" + encodeURI(data) );
}

function ajaxPostForm(url, formElem, onSuccess, onError)
{
 var formData = new FormData(formElem);
 ajaxPostFormData(url, formData, onSuccess, onError)
}

function ajaxPostFormData(url, formData, onSuccess, onError)
{
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.onload = function(){onSuccess(this);}
 ajax.onerror = function(){onError(this);}
 ajax.open("POST",url,true);
 ajax.send(formData);
}

function getTheStyle(tgtElement)
{
 var result = {}, properties = window.getComputedStyle(tgtElement, null);
 forEach(properties, function(prop){result[prop] = properties.getPropertyValue(prop);});
 return result;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
// var image_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/j6oJO8s.png'; 
// var image_url = 'onePixel.png';
 var image_url = 'j6oJO8s.png';
 
 byId('theImage').src = image_url;
 solve_darkest(image_url, function(x,y){alert('x: '+x+' y: '+y);} );
 solve_darkest_2(image_url, function(x,y){alert('x: '+x+' y: '+y);} );
}

function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) 
{
r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
} else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
        case r:
            h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
            break;
        case g:
            h = (b - r) / d + 2;
            break;
        case b:
            h = (r - g) / d + 4;
            break;
    }
    h /= 6;
}

return ({
    h: h,
    s: s,
    l: l,
})
}

function solve_darkest(url, callback) 
{
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = url;

 image.onload = function()
 {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width  = 300;
  canvas.height = 300;

  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300);

  var pixel = 0;
  var darkest_pixel_lightness = 100;
  var darkest_pixel_location = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) 
  {
   var red = imgData.data[i + 0];
   var green = imgData.data[i + 1];
   var blue = imgData.data[i + 2];
   var alpha = imgData.data[i + 3];

   var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
   var lightness = hsl.l;

   if (lightness < darkest_pixel_lightness) 
   {
    darkest_pixel_lightness = lightness;
    darkest_pixel_location = pixel;
    console.log("Darkest found at index: " + pixel);
   }

   pixel++;
  }

 //    var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/200);
 //    var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*200);
  var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location/this.width);
  var x = darkest_pixel_location-(y*this.width);
  callback(x,y);
 };
}



function solve_darkest_2(url, callback) 
{
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = url;

 image.onload = function()
 {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width  = 300;
  canvas.height = 300;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var darkest_pixel_luminance = 100;
  var darkest_pixel_xPos = 0;
  var darkest_pixel_yPos = 0;
  for (var y=0; y<canvas.height; y++)
  {
   for (var x=0; x<canvas.width; x++)
   {
    var luminance = averagePixels(imgData, x, y, 10);
    if (luminance < darkest_pixel_luminance)
    {
     darkest_pixel_luminance = luminance;
     darkest_pixel_xPos = x;
     darkest_pixel_yPos = y;
    }
   }
  }
  callback(darkest_pixel_xPos,darkest_pixel_yPos);
 };
}

function averagePixels(imgData, xPos, yPos, averagingBlockSize)
{
// var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// var imgData = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
// imgData
 
 // we average pixels found in a square region, we need to know how many pixels
 // are in the region to divide the accumalated totals by the number of samples (pixels) in the
 // averaging square
 var numPixelsMax = averagingBlockSize * averagingBlockSize;
 var numPixelsActual = 0;
 
 var red, green, blue;
 red = green = blue = 0;
 
 var rowStride = imgData.width * 4;  // add this to an index into the canvas's data to get the pixel
          // immediatelly below it.
 var x, y;
 var initialIndex = ((yPos * imgData.width) + xPos) * 4;
 var index = initialIndex;
 
 var pixel = 0;
 var darkest_pixel_lightness = 100;
 var darkest_pixel_location = 0;
 
 for (y=0; y<averagingBlockSize; y++)
 {
  index = initialIndex + y * rowStride;
  
  for (x=0; x<averagingBlockSize; x++)
  {
   if ((x+xPos < imgData.width) && (y+yPos < imgData.height))
   {
    red += imgData.data[index+0];
    green += imgData.data[index+1];
    blue += imgData.data[index+2];
    numPixelsActual++;
   }
   index += 4;
  }
 }
 red /= numPixelsActual;
 green /= numPixelsActual;
 blue /= numPixelsActual;
 
 var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
 var luminance = hsl.l;
 return luminance;
}
```

```css
img
{
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
 <h1>300px</h1>
 <img id='theImage'/>
```

Comment: You're correct; hardcoding them to 200x200 was a mistake that was left after I did some testing with another image. With the help of Emestas above I came to this updated JSFiddle jsfiddle.net/brampower/tw08fdhf Unfortunately this is still not the result I was hoping for. I'm trying to get the x and y coords of the darker box of the image; I figured that the darkest pixel would be inside of that box but it does not appear to be that way. I might need to look into testing a region and average the brightness of pixels in the region. Would you be able to steer me into the right direction to do so?

Comment: Sure. Well, you could take the average of (say) 3x3 pixels. I'd use x, x+1, x+2 and y, y+1, y+2. I'd add all the r values, all the g values and then all the b values. I'd then divide the accumulated values by the number of pixels in the region (3x3 = 9) and then convert this single rgb triple to hsl and check for darkest sample so far as you are currently. You'll have to either (0) deal with cases that have less than 9 valid pixels to sample, or (1) do img_side_len - region_side_len iterations through the loop instead of img_side_len iterations. :)

Comment: Whoa, this went way over my head. Looks like I have a lot of fiddling around to do when it comes to Javascript.Would you be able to write up a JSFiddle? I realize that I'm asking a lot, so if you don't have time to do so please don't feel pressured. I completely understand :)

Comment: :laughs: Did the same thing for me when I first tried to code-up the concept. I've taken your original code and made as few modifications to it as were practical. It's about 2am here, so with 24 hours awake now, I'm unable to furnish my best work. You're more than welcome to a refund should the solution be disagreeable! I'll just throw the code together into an answer. (my already existing one)

Comment: Wow, this is incredbile! Much appreciated. I tried to run the code and it threw a ton of errors at me, so I tried to tidy it up a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/brampower/adw4bvmg/

Please let me know if I messed anything up (after you get some rest, of course!) I'm sure I did, because it doesn't seem to want to run at all right now. When ran with Tampermonkey, I get an error on line 86 that I can't seem to get rid of :( It's the following line: byId('theImage').src = image_url; - image_url is defined correctly, so I'm not entirely sure why it wants to hang here.

Comment: No problem. Just had a squiz at your fiddle. The problem I think, is that you've wrapped all of my code inside a closure. Added to that, you've set the fiddle to further wrap the code. As a fiddle, the javascript needs to be set to "no wrap - in head". I've thrown the whole working source onto pastebin and with modification of the image path you'll have a working demo. Here's a link: https://pastebin.com/pV8PLa9k

Comment: Instead of trying to mess with it myself (I am trying to learn, after all), I just took your code, threw it into a html file and ran it on my localhost. I am not getting any errors, however, the alert always says x = 299 and y = 299, no matter what image I use :( Here is a pic of the output: http://i.imgur.com/PtLea2g.png

Comment: Are you seeing the same thing on your end, or is my html file somehow messed up?